# Sending form-data to Java server through a Node middleman

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, java-server, busboy

I have an application that uses *[axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)* to make requests to a *node server* which in turn makes requests to another *java server*.

**Call to node server from client:**

```
// here payload is FormData()
axios.post(url, payload).then((response) => {
    return callback(null, response);
}).catch((err) => {
    return callback(err, null);
});
```

**In the node server**, I listen to the request using *[busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy)*:

```
let rawData = '';
const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});

busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    file.on('data', function (chunk) {
        rawData += chunk;
    });
});
```

Now the java server too expects FormData (just like the way I sent it to node). How do I get the FormData from node now? I have been googling hard and trying a lot of stuff in vain. Any solution not involving *busboy* will help too.

Comment: so is it *Java* or *JavaScript*? The code looks the latter to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had finally used the middleware [busboy-body-parser](https://github.com/lennym/busboy-body-parser) which adds support for getting files from the request object as *req.files*. And once the file is there, I send it as form-data to the java web server using the [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data) npm package. The *req.files* support used to be there by default in [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/). But from 4.x, it has been [deprecated](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req).

[Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is another really good middleware for handling *multipart/form-data*.